# how to input checkbox to database

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.8

I have created a form with 3 checkboxes and when I check one checkbox it successfully puts it into a database. But when I checks more than one checkbox, just one data input makes it into the database, which is the first checkbox data. How to store the data input from all checkboxes ?

These are my codes so far :

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <b>Paket</b>
  <br/>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" name="paket" id="delux" value="Delux"> <label for="">Paket Delux </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="paket" id="p1" value="Paket1"> <label for="">Paket 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="paket" id="p2" value="Paket2"> <label for="">Paket 2</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function proses(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'file'=>'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'makanan'=>'required',
            'jenis'=>'required',
            'paket'=>'required',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        //nama folder tempat file diupload
        $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
        $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);

        Gambar::create([
            'file' =>$nama_file,
            'nama_makanan'=>$request->makanan,
            'kode_jenis'=>$request->jenis,
            'paket'=>$request->paket,
        ]);
        return redirect('/makanan');
    }
```

Comment: `name="paket"` update `name="paket[]"` and `'paket'=>$request->paket,` with `'paket' => implode(',',$request->paket)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : 
Update your all 3 checkbox names

From:

```
name="paket"
```

to:

```
 name="paket[]"
```

and

```
'paket'=>$request->paket,
```

to:

```
'paket' => implode(',',$request->paket`)
```

This will help you out :)

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of _why_ they need to update the code, what it solves and how.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <b>Paket</b>
                    <br/>
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="paket[]" id="delux" value="Delux"> <label for="">Paket Delux </label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="paket[]" id="p1" value="Paket1"> <label for="">Paket 1</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="paket[]" id="p2" value="Paket2"> <label for="">Paket 2</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

public function proses(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'file'=>'required|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
            'makanan'=>'required',
            'jenis'=>'required',
            'paket'=>'required',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');
        $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();

        //nama folder tempat file diupload
        $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
        $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);

        Gambar::create([
            'file' =>$nama_file,
            'nama_makanan'=>$request->makanan,
            'kode_jenis'=>$request->jenis,
            'paket'=>json_encode($request->paket),
        ]);
        return redirect('/makanan');
    }
```